# Front End Entry Form - Proper Syntax for Custom Fields

Tags: templating, frontend-form

I'm working on a front-end entry form with custom text input fields. From the [Entry Form knowledgebase](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/entry-form) docs, I read "Any custom field handles must be provided in a fields[] array like body is above." On that page their example 'body' field is a textarea field, and when I use this with my own textarea fields it works fine. However I'm having trouble formatting that same logic to make a simple plaintext input field work properly.

My current (non-working) code is:

```
 <label for="contactName">Contact Name</label>
  {{ input('text', 'contactName', entry.contactName, {
    id: 'contactName',
    name: 'fields[contactName]'
  }) }}
```

No errors are being thrown when I submit the form, but the values from the plaintext input area are not being saved. What's the proper way to format such that the input values are saved properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the `input` function is the name attribute, which you currently have as `contactName`. Assigning it in the options like you have does not override the initial supplied parameter. Try this:

```
{{ input('text', 'fields[contactName]', entry.contactName, {
    id: 'contactName'
}) }}
```

Comment: Gotcha! That makes perfect sense. Thanks for talking me through it. Works perfectly now. Much appreciated.